# How to sum duplicated values in a Group (SSRS)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

How to sum duplicated values in a Group. *SSRS 2008*

My query returns values like the following:

[image]

But, I want this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing your existing query and/or schema, plus details of what you've already tried and the problem(s) you ran into would be helpful, but if your original query was:

```
SELECT [Cus ID], [Cus Name], [Inv Amt]
FROM Invoices
```

then you want to `GROUP BY` the `[Cus ID]` and `SUM` the `[Inv Amt]` values:

```
SELECT [Cus ID], [Cus Name], SUM([Inv Amt])
FROM Invoices
GROUP BY [Cus ID], [Cus Name]
```